# retrieve only unique values via query

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Here's the formula I currently use:

```
=query(IMPORTRANGE("XXXX","XXXXX!A:H"), 
"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8 
 where Col1> date '"&TEXT(F1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col3 = '"&B1&"' and Col4 = '"&D1&"'
 order by Col1 desc",1)
```

The formula is working.
Col1 includes input dates. I retrieve only values that are after a date listed in F1.
Col3 and Col3 include some properties which are selected in cells B1 and D1, accordingly.
Col5 includes strings (client names). client name can repeat on several rows.
I'd like to retrieve just the most recent one. Any ideas on how to do it?

And, to add more fun into the question, would it be the same idea to retrieve the oldest row per client?

---

Here's a [link to demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg/edit?usp=sharing), details in the "unique query" tab.

Another challenge can be to retrieve X number of row per client, and not just the most recent one.

Comment: what cell does this formula currently live in?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @MattKing - I edited my question with the demo sheet. Thanks

Comment: @player0 - I edited my question with the demo sheet. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg", "Activity list!A:E"), 
 "where Col1 > date '"&TEXT(I2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col2 = '"&I3&"' 
  order by Col1 desc", 1), 99^99, 2, 4, 1)
```

[image]

```
SORTN explained:

99^99    all rows - no limits
2        means "merge mode"
4        collapse 4th column into unique values
1        return 4th column ascending - 0 for descending
```

Comment: thanks. SORTN, which I haven't used before, seems to be a perfect fit for this situation. It works perfectly in the demo sheet, but when I try to replicate it with our live data it returns the wrong data. The original range is an activity log that can have multiple inputs related to a client on any given day. Our goal with the importance is to extract just the most recent N rows related to each client. I tried tweaking the SORTN parameters as per your explanation and the Sheets documentation but couldn't get it to retrieve the data as we want it. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for editing your answer. I might have misunderstood something. Does SORTN look for duplicate rows? Our rows aren't the same, as demonstrated in the demo sheet. It's true that several columns are the same across multiple rows, but some columns aren't the same.

Comment: no, SORTN looks only into one specified column (in this case column 4 - client's name) and creates a set of unique values by trimming out all non-first rows (hance "order by Col1 desc" in query is vital because it sorts the data from recent timestamp to past and then SORTN will just remove the "past")

Comment: ahh!! Now it seems to work but, funny thing, it pushes the headers row from the original range to a random row in the imported range area.

Comment: @player0 "ranking" by name but eliminating ties is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

I am basing myself on a SQL expression that would achieve this result but unfortunately Google Sheets QUERY language is not as expressive. That's why the resulting formula looks a bit confusing.

```
=query(
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg/edit","Activity list!A:E"), 
"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 
where Col1= date'"&
JOIN("' or Col1 = date  '",
  ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
    query(query(
         "THE IMPORTED RANGE", 
         "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 
          where Col1> date '"&TEXT(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 = '"&I3&"'  
          order by Col1 desc",1), 
    "select MAX(Col1), Col4 
     group by Col4 
     order by MAX(Col1) desc 
     label MAX(Col1) ''", 0),
  1000, 1),
  "yyyy-MM-DD")
))&"'",1)
```

Queries specification starting from the inner one:

- Filter the data with your criteria.
- Get the most recent submission grouping by Client.
- Join the results with the whole dataset to fetch the other column values.

  - Use the ARRAY_CONSTRAIN formula to retrieve the columns with the dates.

The same approach goes for the oldest submission changing MAX for MIN aggregate function.

Note: This is not suited for daily multiple submissions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is using a Vlookup into a query().  unfortunately, it involves using the IMPORTRANGE() twice, but I still think it's more efficient than some other possible methods.  You'll find it in A2 of the MK.Help tab on your sample sheet.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(query(IMPORTRANGE("1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg","Activity list!A:E"), "select Col4 where Col1> date '"&TEXT(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 = '"&I3&"' 
 order by Col1 desc",1)),query(IMPORTRANGE("1LoHg53hzQvYtOLTcDwxLY8OrKVN4F7usX8YI41BtdWg","Activity list!A:E"), "select Col4,Col1,Col2,Col3,Col5 where Col1> date '"&TEXT(I2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col2 = '"&I3&"' 
 order by Col1 desc",1),{2,3,4,1,5},0)))
```

Comment: Thanks! this is great. A couple of questions: 1. What does this relate to, at the end of your formula, {2,3,4,1,5},0)))? 2. Can you please explain the logic behind the double IMPORTRANGE, as they seem to be identical? Thanks!

Comment: @user13708028 {2,3,4,1,5} are columns 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... 0 is "exact match". they are not identical... there is VLOOKUP so 1st importrange outputs unique values (1 column) and 2nd importrange returns the rest